# An sql query that lists values that are not the same in one column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find an sql that list the majors that are not offered by armstrong state.

The table is called major

majorNumber --    MajorName      --    -   universityName

1  ---------------         --        art   ------------- --       Austin

2  ---------------    --         automotive    --- -       Fort Smith

3   ---------------    --        Chemistry    ---   --      Armstrong

4     ---------------  --        Chemistry     ---  --      Austin

Comment: look up how to use NOT IN in a select statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from majors where majorName not in (select distinct majorName from
majors where universityName = 'Armstrong')
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of how this answers the question for future reference.

Comment: This is the answer i wanted. It listed all of the majors that are not offered at Armstrong while taking into account the duplicate major names. The was also syntax was alot more familiar than the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Group by the major and take only those having no records for 'Armstrong'

```
select majorName
from major
group by majorName
having sum(universityName = 'Armstrong') = 0
```